# Limit of a jointly independent sequence of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Can I say the following?

If a jointly independent sequence of random variables $X_1,X_2,\dots$  converges to random variable $X$ in the mean square sense, then $X$ is independent of the elements of the sequence too?

Thanks.

Comment: @KarelMacek Convergence in the mean square sense has a specific, precise, meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually $X$ must be almost surely constant.  That is, the variance of $X$ is
$$\text{Cov}(X,X) = \lim_{m,n \to \infty} \text{Cov}(X_m,X_n) = 0$$  A random variable that is a.s. constant is independent of everything.